# Securely send email attachment

Tags: android, security, file, email-attachments

I'm looking to securely send a file as an email attachment on Android (the file contents are private to the user). From all the posts I've read it appears that it's only possible to send a file as an email attachment after creating it on the SD card and providing read access to all (other apps). This appears to be inherently insecure in terms of other users on the device accessing this data (assuming multi-user device).

Is there any way to do this securely on Android?

Comment: Is encryption for the attachment out of the question?

Comment: @Ben Poulson - Correct, no encryption as this would be cumbersome.

Comment: I don't think that encryption is cumbersome, and there will be no secure delivery without encryption at some level (even SSL/TLS).

Comment: @Marcus - in terms of a layperson using the app and having to deal with an encrypted file, I believe it would be cumbersome. Anyway, the file doesn't warrant encryption, but after emailing it, the file shouldn't lie around in a file system that can be accessed by any user of the device.

Comment: Maybe define in your question what you mean by "securely send".

Comment: @Marcus - Sorry for the lack of clarity - by securely I'm looking to ensure that a temporary file (to be attached to an email) is only accessible by the user of my app, and (momentarily) by an email client (to send it!). Unfortunately using temporary files and delete() afterwards doesn't appear to be reliable. I was hoping for a more secure approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From all the posts I've read it appears that it's only possible to send a file as an email attachment after creating it on the SD card and providing read access to all (other apps).

An email program has to be able to read the attachment in order to be able to send the attachment. AFAIK, this is true on every operating system ever created in human history.

That may not necessarily require you to have the file be on external storage (what you refer to as "the SD card"), though I have not tried sending an email attachment using, say, a `ContentProvider` to make the attachment available to other apps. Regardless, you have no good means to limit the read access to only the email client, though you can make access unavailable after a period of time (e.g., after you believe the email has been sent).

> This appears to be inherently insecure in terms of other users on the device accessing this data (assuming multi-user device).

Android is not a multi-user operating system at this time.

> Is there any way to do this securely on Android?

Send it yourself, by writing your own email client, perhaps using the JavaMail for Android port that is floating around.

Comment: thanks, I had considered the JavaMail port - I was just hoping there was a more standard way of doing it. Re: multi-user device - by this I simply mean that more than one individual might be using the device (eg. tablet).

Comment: I agree with CommonsWare. Email clients have simple protocols and are rather easily implemented to the bare minimum necessary for delivering mail.